# openCV face recognition in videos

Tags: opencv, face-recognition

I'm trying make [this](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/tutorial/facerec_video_recognition.html) tutorial but them always are wrong.

How I discover if my train is good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- "but them always are wrong." - well, that's not too helpful, but some reasons. why it might fail:

  1. not enough data. you need like 20 images per person, and for fisher and eigen, you will need more than 5 persons.
  2. badly cropped images. if your test images are cropped from a previous face-detection, your train images should be, too.
  3. bad or no preprocessing. you will have to experiment, if CLAHE, equalizeHist, etc. are improving your score (or are harmful)
- "How I discover if my train is good?" - ofc. you go and test it ! put some of each person's images aside for testing later, train on the others. the lower you can get the threshold value and still regognize correctly, the better your training.